# How to copy user libraries between workspaces in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, copy, workspace, user-defined

I was mistaken in thinking that the user libraries I define in one workspace would be available in all and subsequently created workspaces.

So I created a new workspace to organize the myriad of projects, but alas my user-defined libraries did not get replicated in the new ws.  I am seeking a way to get my user library defs from the old ws into the new ws.

Is there any good way to hack this? (I've tried researching this but have come up empty handed.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an export option, at least as of Eclipse 3.5.2:

`Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > User Libraries > Export...`

If that's not available, what version of Eclipse are you using? Also, what language are you working with? I'm assuming Java, but that wasn't tagged in your question.

Answer (score 2):

In the same place where you define user libraries (under Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries), you will find import/export buttons.